# How to solve this recurrence relation? $f(1) = a; f(2) = b; f(x) = 2f(x-1)-f(x-2)+2;$

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

How to solve this recurrence relation?

- $f(1) = a;$
- $f(2) = b;$
- $f(x) = 2f(x-1)-f(x-2)+2;$

Where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers

I want to find $f(x)$ representation with $a$ and $b$ only

Also I am sorry, I really not familiar with it, I got into this as part of my development project

Comment: Here are the keywords: linear, constant coefficient, inhomogeneous recurrence relation. You'll find many of them solved elsewhere on this site, on the web, in Discrete Math textbooks, ....

Comment: Even without the proper mathematics behind this, you should be able to see a pattern (which could help): $$f(3)=2f(2)-f(1)+2=2b-a+2$$
$$f(4)=2f(3)-f(2)+2=2(2b-a+2)-b+2=3b-2a+6$$
$$f(5)=2f(4)-f(3)+2=2(3b-2a+6)-(2b-a+2)+2=4b-3a+12$$
$$f(6)=2f(5)-f(4)+2=2(4b-3a+12)-(3b-2a+6)+2=5b-4a+20$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ f(x)-2 f(x-1)+f(x-2) = 2 \tag{A}$$
sum both sides over $x\in[3,X]$ to get:
$$ f(X)-f(X-1)-f(2)+f(1) = 2(X-2) $$
$$ f(X)-f(X-1) = 2X-4+b-a \tag{B} $$
the sum both sides over $X\in[3,M]$ to get:
$$ f(M)-b = M^2+M-6+(b-a-4)(M-2). \tag{C}$$
Rearrange and simplify to get that $f(M)$ is a monic, quadratic polynomial in $M$.

Comment: This works because the equation is of the form $(D-1)^2f = 2$. It will not work in general (as you well know).

Comment: @martycohen: of course, but the action of the forward difference operator here is quite evident.

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear recurrence relation. 
Look it up.

First, find the solutions to
$f(n)=2f(n-1)+f(n-2)
$.

Then find the solution to
the whole equation.
Hint:
Try constant, $n, n^2,$ 
... until you find something that works.

Add  these to get the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

By combining all the above clues, we have
\begin{equation}
f(n) = (n-1)b - (n-2)a + (n-1)(n-2)
\end{equation}
To verify this, it is clear that $f(1) = a$ and $f(2) = b$.
Also the simple calculation reveals that
\begin{align}
2f(x-1) - f(x-2) +2 &= 2[(x-2)b - (x-3)a + (x-2)(x-3)] \\
&\hspace{0.2cm} ...- [(x-3)b - (x-4)a + (x-3)(x-4)] + 2 \\
&= (x-1)b - (x-2)a + (x-1)(x-2) = f(x).
\end{align}